# Google Cloud ML - external dependencies

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

i'm working in a ML project, and i need to run a code in Google Cloud ML  but the problem is, my code depends on a [external  package](https://github.com/deepmind/sonnet) that isn't available in standard   **pip** , the usual installation process of this package involves using bazel and a tensorflow installation is needed to compile it.

The problem is that, when i use the gcloud command to submit the job, it fails in the line importing the library.

I'm new to building python packages, but what comes to my mind to solve this, is compile in my computer the library, and upload the .whl files, generated, and pass those .whl to setup.py in order to install them ..

This may work? there is a better approach ?

Thanks for your reading.